# Multiple files move into another directory in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, fs-extra

I want to move multiple files from source directory to destination directory.

I tried with multiple package but its moving the folder itself. but i would like to move one the files contain in the source directory into destination directory.

```
mv('/opt/output/', '/opt/sentFiles' ,function(err) {
    var destination = path.join( '/opt/sentFiles',files[i])
});
```

I tried for child_process then mv package. mv package is working but. its move source folder itself to destination folder. actually i want to move files from source folder exp output/* sentfile/*

Answer (score 3):

You can simply achieve this using the `fs` module, ideally, you have to do is use the [rename](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) function form `fs` module. There is also a Synchronous version [renameSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_renamesync_oldpath_newpath).

According to your requirements, all you have to do is get the list of files you wish to move and loop over to move(rename) them.

Following is the simple test code I tried to move a single file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// Assuming all files are in same folder
let files = ['test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt']; 

// I am using simple for, you can use any variant here
for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var file = files[i];
    fs.rename('./source/' + file, './dest/' + file, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Move complete.');
    });
}

//-------------------------- OUTPUT --------------------------
// Directory Structure Before Move
.
├── dest
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── source
    ├── test1.txt
    ├── test2.txt
    └── test3.txt

// Directory Structure After Move
.
├── dest
│   ├── test1.txt
│   ├── test2.txt
│   └── test3.txt
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── source
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Vivek Molkar,I want to send multiple files. can you help me out this

Comment: @Jaykumar plz check

Comment: Hi @vivek its working for single file move. not for multiple file.
Thanks for your help

Comment: HI Vivek,
I want access array object outside the loop but its returning null value

var result = [];

for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    result.push[i];
}

Comment: Change square brackets to circular ones; `var result = []; for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) { result.push(i); }` push is a function

Comment: Have you tried the edited code? It moves multiple files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182032/discussion-between-vivek-molkar-and-jaykumar).

Answer (score 1):

This task can be done easily with [fs-jetpack](https://github.com/szwacz/fs-jetpack):

```js
const jetpack = require("fs-jetpack");

const src = jetpack.cwd("path/to/source/folder");
const dst = jetpack.cwd("path/to/destination/folder");

// Here assuming we want to move all .txt files, but 
// of corse this can be configured in any way.
src.find({ matching: "*.txt" }).forEach(filePath => {
  src.move(filePath, dst.path(filePath));
});
```

Comment: Thank your for this answer! It's exactly what i was searching for!